# foreach warning coming up

Tags: php

My following code works (it returns the value of text in 2d array).  Now, this is just a proof of concept for something more I want to do (so that's why the logic is stupid)

```
function searchArrayFor($array, $id, $searchFor) {
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        return $value[1];
    }
}
```

So I noticed in my log file, that I am constantly getting "PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".  Everything looks right, and returns the value I want, any ideas on why I keep getting this error?  I really don't want to be spamming the log file with every page load.

using PHP version 5.3.28 (I know, really old version).

Thanks

Comment: `php` is giving warning that the `$array` passed to the function is not an `array`, simple enough. Also, it'll just return in the first iteration.

Comment: There's no way this function is returning anything if that warning is being raised, since it isn't entering the loop.

Comment: $array is an array (I triple checked it), and it is pulling the value i expect from the internal array.

Comment: How you use/call your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I think you might have variables that are not array

```
function searchArrayFor($array, $id, $searchFor) {
    $index = 0;
    if(is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value)
        {
            return $value[1];
        }
    }
    // Maybe add ELSE here and do a die($array); to see which value is not array
}
```

I believe this will take care of your array warning, let me know if that works.

Cheers

Comment: Ok, you found the problem!  I'm new to PHP and didn't think about it, but the array can be empty at times.  Guess I'm just to used to strongly typed languages...

Comment: @Limey yeah, I had similar issue in the past, some funny scenarios happen that you don't think about.. Best of luck with your development!!

Comment: You can use `searchArrayFor(array $array, $id, $searchFor)`

Comment: @TheAlpha my version of php is to old for it.

Comment: You can because it's available since `5.1.0`.

Comment: hmmm...i will have to take a look.  I think the issue was the second dimension on the array.  it needed another function for the column name, which wasn't available till 5.5....if i remember correctly.